# Installing Python 2.5.2 on OS X 10.6

Tags: python, macos, gcc, installation

I am installing Python 2.5.2 on my Mac (OSX 10.6).

I downloaded the source, ran `./configure`, and then ran `make`. I received this error:

```
gcc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
make: *** [Modules/python.o] Error 1
```

What's the deal?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue6802 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821957/compile-python-2-5-5-on-os-x-10-6/3824511#3824511).  While you can build it from scratch with the suggested patches, it may be a lot easier to just download a prebuilt installer from python.org as suggested there.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite it; it is installed to a different path. You should find it is linked at `/usr/local/bin/python2.5`.  But if you are saying you had a python.org python2.5.4 installed (linked to at `/usr/local/bin/python2.5`) and you now want to replace that with an earlier Python 2.5.2 installer, try removing the newer version first: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5` and then re-run the 2.5.2 installer.  Do not attempt to remove the Apple-supplied Python in `/usr/bin/python2.5` and `/System/Library/Frameworks`.