# Python 2.5.6 build error on Mac Lion

Tags: python, build, osx-lion, web2py

Here is what I would like to do.
Use web2py with MySQL.

To do that, I need to use source web2py rather than web2py.app
To use web2py, I need Python 2.5

I am having trouble building and installing Python 2.5

I downloaded Python-2.5.6.tgz from Python release page.
Now, I did

> ./configure

and then

> make

Then, I get the following error.

> gcc -c -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp
>   -mno-fused-madd -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c 
>   cc1: error: unrecognized command line option
>   "-Wno-long-double" make: *** [Modules/python.o] Error 1

Can anybody help me how to get rid of this error and install Python 2.5?

Here is gcc I am using

> gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build
>   2336.9.00)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4301891/776084.

Comment: Why do you need Python 2.5?  That's obsolete and no longer supported.  Use a current Python that is supported on OS X Lion, like the 64-bit/32-bit Python 2.7.3 installer from python.org.  Or use a package manager like MacPorts or Homebrew.  Or, if you must use Python 2.5, why not use the one Apple suppies in Lion, /usr/bin/python2.5?

Comment: Ned, I know there's /usr/bin/python2.5, but how can I use it from command line? I tried python25 but it didn't work.

Comment: Try python2.5 you left out the .   - however using a more modern python is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web2py works fine with Lion's stock Python 2.7. Unless you have a compelling reason to use 2.5, stick with 2.7.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know why but because of the documentation, I thought I had to use Python2.5

Answer (score 0):

I have web2py on my iMac OSX Lion using the web2py app and MySQL. I haven't run into any reason why you can't use the app with MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The documentation said that web2py.app can only use sqlite, if I wanted to connect to other db, I had to compile from source. I should've tried it first.

Answer (score 0):

To install Python on OS X, try using the Universal Binaries provided on python.org (documented at http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html).

See http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.4/python-2.5.4-macosx.dmg for the most recent Universal Binary for Python 2.5.